# NGINX GZIP in ssl server block

Tags: nginx, gzip

Since I added the gzip block to my NGINX conf, the page returns a 404 for most static files (.js, .css, .png etc.) and `was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)` for the vue build files while in server:80 block.

The files do have `content-encoding: gzip` response header

nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.domain.dev;

    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri permanent;
}

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    listen      443 ssl http2;
    server_name *.domain.dev;

    location /static {
        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 256;
        gzip_buffers 4 32k;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        alias /home/ubuntu/code/domain_test/static;
        expires 1y;
    }

    //... rest of config
}
```

If I move the GZIP block to the server:443 config, it works. Is the gzip block supposed to be in the ssl block, because of the redirect?